# Recover passwords from Android browser

Tags: data-recovery, browser, password

I have an Android 5.1 device. I have saved my passwords for some web pages in the Android browser (default browser). Whenever I need it, I just open the page and I am already signed in. Somehow, something has happened. Now it asks me for the password which I forgot. My phone is always locked and no one else can possibly open it, so I don't know what happened exactly and why.

I can't choose to click the password recovery/forgot password, as I used a college email address and now is blocked/deleted.

I'm ready to do anything with the phone, root and all. I read some reviews about rooting and then recovering the passwords from `webview.db` from `/data/data/com.android.browser`, but, this folder is empty. Not sure where to locate `webview.db`, does it show up only after rooting?

I will really really appreciate any tips or advice on this.

Answer (score 0):

Android browser should automatically back up any passwords on your Google account (the college email, but signed in on Google). The first step I'd try is to [recover your google account](https://accounts.google.com/signin/recovery).

Hopefully, you had some alternative contact methods (secondary email, registered phone number, chosen account trustee, etc). These allow you (sometimes) bypass password entry provided you answer any questions accurately enough.

In my last use of the recovery option, it asked me about previous Google purchases and significant email communications and it let me in after 24 hours.

Beyond this, I am unsure if rooting your device will be successful as major parts of the OS are.